# Write to .txt file?

Tags: c, linux

How can I write a little piece of text into a `.txt` file?
I've been Googling for over 3-4 hours, but can't find out how to do it.

`fwrite();` has so many arguments, and I don't know how to use it.

What's the easiest function to use when you only want to write a name and a few numbers to a `.txt` file?

```
char name;
int  number;
FILE *f;
f = fopen("contacts.pcl", "a");

printf("\nNew contact name: ");
scanf("%s", &name);
printf("New contact number: ");
scanf("%i", &number);

fprintf(f, "%c\n[ %d ]\n\n", name, number);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: @user1054396: The problem isn't with the printing (which you got right), but with the *reading* via `scanf`. If you read `%s`, you must read into a buffer of sufficient length, not a single char.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* print some text */
const char *text = "Write this to the file";
fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

/* print integers and floats */
int i = 1;
float pi= 3.1415927;
fprintf(f, "Integer: %d, float: %f\n", i, pi);

/* printing single characters */
char c = 'A';
fprintf(f, "A character: %c\n", c);

fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 23):

```
FILE *fp;
char* str = "string";
int x = 10;

fp=fopen("test.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL)
    exit(-1);
fprintf(fp, "This is a string which is written to a file\n");
fprintf(fp, "The string has %d words and keyword %s\n", x, str);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score -10):

Well, you need to first get a good book on C and understand the language.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("c:\\test.txt", "wb");
if(fp == null)
   return;
char x[10]="ABCDEFGHIJ";
fwrite(x, sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]), fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: That's hard work compared to using `fprintf()` or `fputs()`.  Especially `fprintf()` since a few numbers must be written too.

Comment: And `"c:\\test.txt"` is an unlikely file name; the question is tagged [tag:linux].

Comment: -1 The OP asked for the easiest function to use. And to write text, but you're opening the file in binary mode. And it's poor practice to fail to report an open error.