# How to protect your code during cloud-computing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, cloud, hpc

Before I buy my first setup. I'll launch my deep-learning-pipline on sth like vast.ai.
I never did it before, but How can I protect my script from being "stolen"?

This should be a serious launch and take around 7 days to finish training.
google colab doesn allow enough memory & ram for what i need ( need around 64GB ram)

is there a way to run a python script encrypted? (note: it makes use of libaries)

Comment: This won’t answer your question, but if you’re comfortable using Google Colab for a private project, you probably shouldn’t worry too much about protecting this script.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to run python encrypted. However, you could try to store the code into encrypted disk space.

Comment: its more about executing :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, from fully obfuscating your script to converting your script into equivalent cython or creating an executable out of it using the likes of [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/).
You may also implement some important logic in C/C++ (as extensions) and then call them in your script.
You may also set up a server where you feel is OK and send the bits that needs to be executed, basically create a distributed system.
As you can see there are many ways, and the deeper you go the more complex it gets.

Also you might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864682/encrypt-unencrypt-python-scripts-in-c) as well.