# How to write in txt file using C by Eclipse (typing by console)

Tags: c, eclipse-luna

I was trying to find an answer for this in some internet pages, at the end I tried here and found an answer similar but it doesn't satisfy at all my question

[Here answers how to write some text by writing it in a constant, but it doesn't allows you to whrite by console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573974/write-to-txt-file)

Im so novice in programming world so I apologize if it's too ordinary my question. In addition, I apollogize about my english skills too.

Thanks in advance.

```
  #include "modificator.h"

    int main(void) {
        editFile();
        return 0;
    }

    void editFile() {
        FILE* f;
        Cadena cad, res;  //"Cadena is an array of char"

        printf("Write the access rout to file required: \n");
        scanf("%s", cad);

        f = fopen(cad, "w");

        if (f == NULL) {
            printf("Wrong opening file\n");
        }
        const char *text = scanf("%s", res);    
        fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", text);

        fclose(f);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> const char *text = scanf("%s", res);
> ```

No, no, no. `scanf()` returns a value of `int` type

```
int chk = scanf("%s", res); // beware buffer overflows
if (chk == 1) {
    fprintf(f, "Some text: %s\n", res);
}
```

Comment: That was a huge mistake. Thanks. Now the problems are different. It doesn't show the "printf" phrase and whrite no more than one word in spite of I give a char array of 256 spaces and get the message with the specificator "%s".

Comment: `scanf()` with `%s` ignores whitespace. You may be better off with `fgets()`

Comment: But I don't want to scan or get something from file, only write in whatever I place by console

Comment: `fgets()` can read from `stdin` ==> assuming `res` to be an array of char: `while (fgets(res, sizeof res, stdin)) { /* do your thing with res; you may want to remove the final ENTER in res */ }`

Comment: Now it never ends taking text, and it keeps not showing me printf at begin of code. Thanks for your help and time, Maybe another day I'll try it again