# Prevent line being printed to command line pipe to file

Tags: c, command-line

The title maybe a little confusing.. so here is my attempt of explaining it:

I have a command for my program:

```
c file1.txt > file2.txt
```

This command in the commandline takes the first file and pipes the output of the program (that is printed) to the second file.

So im scanning a user message in:

```
printf("Enter a message:");
char *message = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
scanf("%s", message);
printf("Your message is: %s", message);
```

But this prints both `printf(...)` statements to my piped file, whereas I only want the second one. How can i prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write to .txt file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573974/write-to-txt-file)

Comment: Use a `--quiet` option do suppress such output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `stderr` for the information you don't want copied to the output file:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Enter a message:");
```

Comment: That does not work, it still prints that to the ouput file

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: What? This definitely should *not* be the case for the piping statement as per your question.

Comment: @alk it still writes to the file, i dont want to print it to the file

Comment: Nevermind, i had other print statements with the same strings, thanks!